# Asyncro wait for a timer to expire in Python

Tags: python, timer

So,
I come to C in embedded programming where there's the function `HAL_SYSTICK_Callback` which is executed on every clock tick. With it, knowing the CPU clock, you can create timers in a way like

```
t_1ms = 1

if(t_1ms)
   t_1ms--;
```

And in the main code check if `if(!t_1ms) do something`

Now, I would like to do something like this in Python where, at a certain point in the code I load a timer and then in another part of the code, I check if the timer is exprired.

While executing the code, the timer must count by its onw without blocking the main code.

I've see libraries like [waiting](https://pypi.org/project/waiting/) but they all seem blocking.

Comment: capture timestamp one with `time.monotonic()`, keep running the code, compare against 2nd instance of `time.monotonic()`. No need for a timer if you'll only check in specific place.

Comment: Did you take a look at [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#scheduling-callbacks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggest by [matszwecja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9296093/matszwecja), the use of `time.monotonic()` is more than sufficient for my use case

```
import time

start = time.monotonic()
# code that does something
end = time.monotonic()
if end - start > 1:
   # check if more than 1 second has been spent
   # do something else
```